# How to get the sum of this ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<InvoiceServiceType id: 1, value_charged: 50.0, invoice_id: 4, service_type_id: 1>, #<InvoiceServiceType id: 2, value_charged: 50.4, invoice_id: 4, service_type_id: 2>]>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<InvoiceServiceType id: 8, value_charged: 70.0, invoice_id: 1, service_type_id: 2>, #<InvoiceServiceType id: 9, value_charged: 50.0, invoice_id: 1, service_type_id: 6>]>]
```

I want to sum all value_charged .

im  try map(&:value_charged).sum
collect..
and nothing :(

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you have a `@object` with a `has_many` relationship `details`, and `details` have a field call `:value_charged`, you could try sum all the `:value_charged` of `@object.details` with:

```
@object.details.sum(:value_charged)
```